# Can I continue/restart firing kiln after error

Tags: ceramics, pottery, kiln

What is the best thing to do after an error mid-firing?

Background: I started a cone 6 glaze firing (honyaki) this morning in the hope I could beat the outside temperature (predicted to get to 31°C (87.8°F).
I had windows opened in the morning and fans directed at the kiln/controller unit but around
8 hours into the firing at a temperature of 1200°C (2192°F), I got an error message "E-db", meaning that the controller board detected a high internal temperature and stopped the firing. I have restarted a firing in the past after a power issue, but in this case, the error blocks the kiln from directly starting again.

I am using an Excel Select Fire model EX324SF. I was firing a cone 6 with a 25-minute hold.

Can I continue/restart firing the kiln after an error?
What is the best thing to do?

Comment: Welcome to Arts & Crafts. The question is outside my area, but just an observation that might help get you an answer. I assume the question is about the firing process rather than specifically about unique properties of this particular kiln. If that's the case, it may help to make the question title more generic, and focused on restarting firing in general. By focusing on the error message of this specific kiln, readers may tend to skip the question if they aren't familiar with that specific equipment. Good luck with this.

Comment: Thanks, @fixer1234 I have updated the question to be a bit more general.